# Is dbContext effects on performance of WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

```
 public DEV_MasterPOSEntities Context = new DEV_MasterPOSEntities();
```

I am using WPF and MVVM but system performance is very slow. Is it due to Context? Is it then what can I do to increase performance?

Comment: Not a real question. What you're doing with the context should be the problem. How your Database looks like is another possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent given enough information for us to really be able to pinpoint your problem but if Entity Framework is causing your performance issues I would recommend taking a look at my [cheat sheet](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/08/entity-framework-performance-cheat-sheet.html) for making EF applications as fast as possible.

I also have some other articles around perfomance issues with tracking too many entities:

- [Auto Detect Changes](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/05/entityframework-performance-and.html)
- [AsNoTracking](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html)

Comment: Not every question should get an answer, IMO.

Comment: @gdoron I totally agree. I've done quite a lot of research into making EF fast and i felt that this might provide a starting point for the OP (and other readers) to help diagnose EF performance problems.